# Importing Error of TensorFlow via JupyterLab on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

Recently, I've downloaded TensorFlow, it's working when I start IPython using the terminal with the command `jupyter-notebook`. However, when I use `jupyter-lab` I can't import TensorFlow.

I tried to reinstall TensorFlow again, but it isn't working. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

n.b. I'm using MacOS with M1 chip (I'm not sure if that's relevant anyway).

Comment: Have you tried to follow a guide like [that](https://mobiarch.wordpress.com/2021/09/24/installing-tensorflow-in-macos-m1-chip/)? It seams that you need to install tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal at least.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this way on jupyterlab:

```
!pip install tensorflow-macos
```